# Content script for specific URLs on a SPA site with "fake" navigation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

At the moment I'm testing this code. My intention is to scrape some data using a content script

This is what I have in background file

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener( (tab) => {
    // chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    //     target: {tabId: tab.id},
    //     files: ['content.js']
    //   })
    console.log('Requesting tab: \n', tab)
    chrome.windows.create({
        type: 'popup',
        height: 300,
        width: 200,
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html')
    })
})
```

This is what I have in my content script

```js
console.info('chrome-ext template-vue-js content script')


const DOMnodes = document.querySelectorAll('article')

console.log(`Ecco le informazioni sui prezzi per Sole365`)
console.log('\n')


let details = []

DOMnodes.forEach( (node) => {
    // Loop nodi prodotto
    details.push(node.dataset)
    console.log(`----\n`)
    console.log(`Nome prodotto: ${node.dataset.productName}`)
    console.log(`Descrizione breve: ${node.children[2].children[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].innerText}`)
    // price 
    console.log(`Prezzo: ${node.childNodes[2].childNodes[1].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].innerText}`)
    //console.log(``)
    //descriz. breve
    //node.children[2].children[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].innerText
})

console.log(details)
```

The script isn't executed when the website I set in manifest match. here is the dev version

```json
{
  "name": "create-chrome-ext",
  "description": "Extract data",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "icons": {
    "16": "img/logo-16.png",
    "32": "img/logo-34.png",
    "48": "img/logo-48.png",
    "128": "img/logo-128.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "img/logo-48.png"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker-loader.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://www.example.com/mypath/*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "assets/content-script.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://www.example.com/mypath/*/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "matches": [],
      "resources": [
        "img/logo-16.png",
        "img/logo-34.png",
        "img/logo-48.png",
        "img/logo-128.png"
      ],
      "use_dynamic_url": false
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "resources": [
        "**/*",
        "*"
      ],
      "use_dynamic_url": true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "alarms"
  ]
}
```

Any idea of why? My idea is to call the script when the icon is clicked and open a popup to get the resulting extracted data to use in vue frontent

Answer (score 2):

**Problem #1:** in Chrome you need to [reinject the content script(s)](/q/10994324) to handle reload/update/install.

**Problem #2:** the site is a modern SPA (Single Page Application) which fakes navigation via `history.pushState` or the hash fragment, so the page document stays the same (only DOM is changed) and the content script doesn't re-run. The content script won't run at all if the user first opened an unmatching URL like the home page of the site.

- set content script's `"matches"` to the entire site e.g. `"*://www.example.com/*"`
- use MutationObserver in the content script and either check for the presence of telltale elements you want to target or check if `location.href` has changed to the previously saved value in a global variable, for example:

  ```js
  let lastUrl = location.href; 
  new MutationObserver(() => {
    const url = location.href;
    if (url !== lastUrl) {
      lastUrl = url;
      onUrlChange();
    }
  }).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});

  function onUrlChange() {
    console.log('URL changed!', location.href);
  }
  ```
- alternatively, if you have the background script, use `chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated` and `onReferenceFragmentUpdated` there. It can be limited via [URL filter](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/events/#type-UrlFilter). Your listener for these events will send a message to the tab id of the event, which will be received by your content script ([example](/a/51025612)).

To verify this is a SPA:

1. open devtools -> Network panel
2. click `Doc` or `Document` or `HTML` in the toolbar filter for request types
3. click a link in the page to navigate within the site
4. see if the request for the link's URL is added to the network log

Comment: At the moment I'm testing by using scripting api, but I have some vit config problem