# service-worker.js file doesnt receive message sent from content.js file

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i got one gg extension  project,

problem is my service-worker.js file doesnt receive message sent from content.js file.

now i'm using v3.

here is my manifest file.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "matches": [
        "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/*",
        "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/*",
        "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "description": "Công cụ hỗ trợ thay đổi IP trên các trình duyệt!",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "proxy",
    "storage",
    "<all_urls>",
    "alarms",
    "tabs",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "incognito": "spanning",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "32": "images/icon32.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "102",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["logo.png"],
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

In content.js file, I custom sendMessage like  this

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log("_request__", request);
});

sendMessageForBackground('stop-auto-change-ip', {}, {});
```

in service-worker.js , listener config

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log('_request__',request);
    }
  );
```

Now I want to see config after I call **sendMessageForBackground** func

Comment: This site is a SPA, so it uses the same document, meaning your content script won't run when navigating within the site. You should specify the entire site in `matches`  without a path, and check the urls inside the content script. See [Chrome extension - Execute content script for specific site url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73673829)